# Facing issue in running while loop in caesar-cipher encode and decode problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def caesar(start_text, shift_amount, cipher_direction):
  end_text = ""
  if cipher_direction == "decode":
    shift_amount *= -1
  for char in start_text:
    if char in alphabet:
   
      position = alphabet.index(char)
      if shift_amount > 26:
        new_shift = shift_amount % 26
        new_position = position + new_shift
      else:
        new_position = position + shift_amount
      end_text += alphabet[new_position]
    else:
      end_text += char
      
      
  print(f"Here's the {cipher_direction}d result: {end_text}")
  answer = input("Type 'yes' if you want to go again. Otherwise type 'no'.")
  if answer == "yes":
    run_again = True
  if answer == "no":        //This part is not working 
    run_again = False


run_again = True
while run_again:
  
  direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
  text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
  shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
  
  caesar(start_text=text, shift_amount=shift, cipher_direction=direction)
```

when I press "no" on answer still programme goes on . I want to stop the program when user types no . while loop should stop there but while loop is going on anyways . I dont understand what I am missing.

Comment: You are setting `run_again` inside the `caesar` function - this is a differently scoped variable to the one set at the top level. You should read up on variable scope in python, and instead probably return something from `caesar` to interrupt the `while` loop.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing the "run again" part inside the `caesar` function at all.  It's simpler if the `caesar` function *just* does the caesar cipher logic -- do all the user input stuff in your loop and all the cipher stuff in your function, so that each type of code is in its own place.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the value of a variable declared outside a method from within a method.
The `run_again` variable inside the method is different from the `run_again` variable you have declared outside the method. Hence, the value of `run_again` outside the method is always true, no matter what you do inside the method.

An easy fix without modifying much would be

```
if answer == "no":        
    return = False
else:
    return True
```

And when you call the method

`run_again = caesar(start_text=text, shift_amount=shift, cipher_direction=direction)`

What this essentially does is that when you enter no, the method returns the value `False` to the function call which gets assigned to the run_again **outside the function**.

Note: This way will make the least changes to your code, but the ideal way is how Samwise suggested in the comments.